# Работа с функцией VirtualAlloc()

Tags: c++, c++builder

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как через Edit ввести параметр dwSize в функции VirtualAlloc()?
Когда пишу просто в самой функции размер региона:

```
p = VirtualAlloc(NULL,4096,MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_READONLY);
```

то все работает нормально.
А как сделать так чтобы в параметр dwSize (второй параметр) считывался с Edit в С++ Builder

Comment: Вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к `VirtualAlloc`

Comment: а к чему тогда? объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Ваш вопрос о том, как перевести строку (из Edit или еще откуда) в число. А откуда взялась эта строка и куда потом пойдет это число никакого значения не имеет.

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = Edit1->Text.ToInt();
```

Comment: не работает корретно, я добавил скрин ошибки

Comment: @Кирилл Ненахов  Вам нужно перевести, что означает "is not a valid integer value"? Что содержится  в Edit?